# Gsutil Always Time Out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am just learning the Google Cloud with Keras, but once when I need to use Gsutil to submit a project, it always is time out. I feel confused about. It seems not a networking problem, I can connect to google cloud except Gsutil.

```
(python2.7) (base) Dereks-MacBook-Pro:tf-keras derekgrant$ gsutil -D mb -l us-east1 gs://my-awesome-bucket/
***************************** WARNING *****************************
*** You are running gsutil with debug output enabled.
*** Be aware that debug output includes authentication credentials.
*** Make sure to remove the value of the Authorization header for
*** each HTTP request printed to the console prior to posting to
*** a public medium such as a forum post or Stack Overflow.
***************************** WARNING *****************************
gsutil version: 4.38
checksum: 58d3e78c61e7e0e80813a6ebc26085f6 (OK)
boto version: 2.49.0
python version: 2.7.16 (default, Nov  9 2019, 05:55:08) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s
OS: Darwin 19.2.0
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
pass cloud sdk credentials to gsutil: True
config path(s): /Users/derekgrant/.boto, /Users/derekgrant/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/derekgrant01@gmail.com/.boto
gsutil path: /Users/derekgrant/GoogleCloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
Command being run: /Users/derekgrant/GoogleCloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=my-project-trainning -D mb -l us-east1 gs://my-awesome-bucket/
config_file_list: ['/Users/derekgrant/.boto', '/Users/derekgrant/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/derekgrant01@gmail.com/.boto']
config: [('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('https_validate_certificates', 'True'), ('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('content_language', 'en'), ('default_api_version', '2'), ('default_project_id', 'my-project-trainning')]
Creating gs://my-awesome-bucket/...
WARNING 0205 18:03:13.102274 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Failed to obtain interprocess lock for credentials. If a credential is being refreshed, other processes may not see the updated access token and refresh as well.
WARNING 0205 18:03:13.103058 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0205 18:03:13.103420 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
WARNING 0205 18:03:13.103881 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0205 18:03:13.104093 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
INFO 0205 18:03:13.107666 base_api.py] Calling method storage.buckets.insert with StorageBucketsInsertRequest: <StorageBucketsInsertRequest
 bucket: <Bucket
 acl: []
 cors: []
 defaultObjectAcl: []
 location: u'us-east1'
 name: u'my-awesome-bucket'>
 project: 'my-project-trainning'
 projection: ProjectionValueValuesEnum(full, 0)>
INFO 0205 18:03:13.109338 base_api.py] Making http POST to https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=my-project-trainning&alt=json&projection=full
INFO 0205 18:03:13.110032 base_api.py] Headers: {'accept': 'application/json',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'content-length': '53',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'user-agent': 'apitools gsutil/4.38 Python/2.7.16 (darwin) google-cloud-sdk/245.0.0 analytics/enabled'}
INFO 0205 18:03:13.110248 base_api.py] Body:
{"location": "us-east1", "name": "my-awesome-bucket"}
INFO 0205 18:03:13.110522 transport.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
WARNING 0205 18:03:14.111114 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Failed to obtain interprocess lock for credentials. If a credential is being refreshed, other processes may not see the updated access token and refresh as well.
WARNING 0205 18:03:14.111579 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0205 18:03:14.111897 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
WARNING 0205 18:03:14.112537 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Credentials file could not be loaded, will ignore and overwrite.
DEBUG 0205 18:03:14.112798 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Read credential file
INFO 0205 18:03:14.113228 reauth_creds.py] Refreshing access_token
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Also, could you try to follow the steps to install gsutil again using the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install)? The problem might be related with your credentials, since in one of the lines, it could be seen the following message: `WARNING 0205 18:03:13.102274 multiprocess_file_storage.py] Failed to obtain interprocess lock for credentials. If a credential is being refreshed, other processes may not see the updated access token and refresh as well.`.

Comment: Please try to follow the documentation to set up credentials to [access protected data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate) since it's likely you didn't define your credentials on your machine and thus `gsutil` can not be reached. I hope it helps.

Comment: @ChristopherRodriguezConde Many thanks, I could run the gsutil in the Google Colab. But it doesn't work in the terminal in the same way. What really is cofusing me is that I don't whether is the credential problem or network proxy problem,

Comment: @DerekGrant - Did you find the root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output seems incomplete, after "Refreshing access_token", you should see either:

```
connect: (oauth2.googleapis.com, 443)
```

or an error.

One of the errors, due to a proxy, could be:

```
proxy: ('10.0.0.1', 3210, True, None, None, None)
DEBUG 1103 00:00:0.0 http_wrapper.py] Caught socket error, retrying: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

If there's an issue with the proxy, then expect:

```
socket.timeout: timed out
```